# How to convert List<List<string>> to a DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

How would I convert `List<List<string>>` to a `DataTable`? I am trying to set the `DataSource` of a gridview to a `List<List<string>>` variable.

Comment: What would the table look like?

Comment: what are the columns for the table?

Comment: See other answer below, you probably do not need to convert to DataTable only to assign as datasource to the GridView, if you bind properly your control you can skip such conversion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can easily be done using extension methods.

Add this class to your solution

```
static class ListExtensions
{
    public static DataTable ToDataTable(this List<List<string>> list)
    {
        DataTable tmp = new DataTable();
        foreach (List<string> row in list)
        {
            tmp.Rows.Add(row.ToArray());
        }
        return tmp;
    }
}
```

then use the extension method like this:

```
List<List<string>> myList = new List<List<string>>();
// Fill with values...
DataTable table = myList.ToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public static DataTable ToDataTable(this List<List<string>> list)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    list.First().ForEach(colname => dt.Columns.Add(colname));
    foreach (List<string> row in list.Skip(1))
        dt.Rows.Add(row.ToArray());
    return dt;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would rather set DataSource of the grid to BindableList, which you would perhaps create easier, instead of double nested List, you would have List of Rows (where the Row is business entity represented, for example Customer).

Comment: The question is List<List<string>>.  I tried BindingList<List<string>> and it did not work.