# How to dynamically set source of DataGridView in C#?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have some List for storage data

`List<List<string>> data = new List<List<string>>();`

How to correctly assign it to `dataGridView.DataSource` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is (obviously) the DataGridView DataSource property doesn't know how to display a `List<List<string>>`.  One approach is to combine your Lists into one object which the DataGridView can bind to.  Here are a couple ways to do this:

**To a DataTable:**

To convert your `List<List<string>>` to a DataTable, I borrowed the code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344939/how-to-convert-listliststring-to-a-datatable) and created this extension method:

```
static class ListExtensions { 
    public static DataTable ToDataTable(this List<List<string>> list) { 
        DataTable tmp = new DataTable();
        tmp.Columns.Add("MyData");
        // Iterate through all List<string> elements and add each string value to a new DataTable Row.        
        list.ForEach(lst => lst.ForEach(s => tmp.Rows.Add(new object[] {s})));

        return tmp; 
    } 
}
```

Here's now you can use this extension method to get a DataTable from your `List<List<string>>` which you can bind to your DataGridView:

```
dataGridView.DataSource = data.ToDataTable();
```

**To an anonymous type List:**

Here is the code for doing this:

```
dataGridView.DataSource = data.SelectMany(lst => lst)
                              .Select(s => new { Value = s }).ToList();
```

We need the anonymous type because a DataGridView won't be able to display the string values in List property without a little help, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479329/how-to-bind-a-string-list-to-a-datagrid).

---

There are of course disadvantages to either these approaches but I do believe something along these lines is your best option.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<List<string>> data = new List<List<string>>();
dataGridView.DataSource = data;
dataGridView.Databind();
```

as some posters stated this was for windows forms in which case you can (according to MSDN) jst set the datasurce and not databind

Comment: DataGridView in Windows Forms.