# Converting arbitrarily nested lists to POCOs or DataTables

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datatable, poco

I like to use nested Lists like `List<List<double>>`. Unfortunately I am using a library that only supports POCOs, ie plain old clr objects or DataTables.

Is there a way to create a POCO or DataTable out of `List<List<double>>` or `List<myClass>` for my library to work with?

In other words the same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344939/how-to-convert-listliststring-to-a-datatable?lq=1) but not for string but for an arbitrarily nested list `List<List<double>>` or `List<myClass>`.

Comment: please post some code... not clear what you're asking

Comment: What your library should do with these objects?

Comment: @Alex In other words the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344939/how-to-convert-listliststring-to-a-datatable?lq=1 but not for string but for an arbitrarily nested list `List<List<double>>` or `List<myClass>`.